Large file transfers slow with HTTP but fast with SCP
I need to transfer 432 MB images between 2 Linux computers which are on the same fast network.  scp transfers each image in less than 1 second.  The code below using HTTP takes between 3 and 8 seconds per image.
The client and server computers have no load other than this transfer process.  CPU and disk utilization on both the computers are low.  There are no other requests being processed by the HTTP server process.  Both the HTTP and scp file transfers succeed.  There are no errors and I received no timeout messages.
I understand HTTP has more overhead than scp, but I would not expect it to increase the transfer time by over 3x.
I've spent more than 1 hour fruitlessly looking for reasons for this performance difference.  Chatbots are no help.
Can you please let me know if this is expected and if there are any ways to get the HTTP transfer to more closely approach scp performance.
Code used for the HTTP process:
client.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse
import requests
import sys,os

# Predefined variables
SERVER = 'ua02861p.abbvienet.com'
PORT = 8443


def upload_image(image_path, url, verify_ssl):
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as img:
        files = {'file': img}
        response = requests.post(url, files=files, verify=verify_ssl)
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print(f"HTTP error: {e}")
        return response.json()

    return response.json()

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Upload images to a FastAPI server.")
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--server', type=str, default=SERVER, help=f'Server address (hostname or IP) [default: {SERVER}]')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=PORT, help=f'Port number [default: {PORT}]')
    parser.add_argument('--use-http', action='store_true', default=False, help='Use HTTPS instead of HTTP [default: True]')
    parser.add_argument('--verify-ssl', action='store_true', default=False, help='Enable SSL certificate verification [default: False]')
    parser.add_argument('filenames', type=str, nargs='+', help='One or more image file paths')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    protocol = "http" if args.use_http else "https"
    server = args.server
    port = args.port
    filenames = args.filenames
    verify_ssl = args.verify_ssl

    url = f"{protocol}://{server}:{port}/upload-image/"

    for image_path in filenames:
        print(f"Uploading {image_path} to {url} ", end = '')
        ''' redirecting stderr to remove the annoying verify ssl warning '''
        stderr = sys.stderr 
        sys.stderr = open(os.devnull,'w')
        response = upload_image(image_path, url, verify_ssl)
        sys.stderr = stderr
        print(f"({response['info']})")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

server.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Request, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from pathlib import Path
import uvicorn
import requests
import os
import sys

# Defaults
# SERVER = 'ua02861p.abbvienet.com' #
SERVER = '0.0.0.0' #LISTEN to all interfaces
PORT = 8443

def fpath(file_path):
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        #print(f"The file '{file_path}' exists.")
        return file_path
    else:
        # Prepend the script directory to the file_path
        script_directory= os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
        #print (f'script_directory = {type (script_directory)}')
    
        modified_file_path = os.path.join(script_directory, file_path)
        #print(f"The modified file path '{modified_file_path}' exists. {type (modified_file_path)}")
        if os.path.exists(modified_file_path):
            return modified_file_path
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"{file_path} does not  exist.")

app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=422,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors(), "body": exc.body}),
    )

@app.post("/upload-image/")
async def upload_image(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    file_location = f"uploaded_images/{file.filename}"
    Path("uploaded_images").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open(file_location, "wb") as buffer:
        buffer.write(await file.read())
    return {"info": "file uploaded successfully", "filename": file.filename}

def get_module_name():
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]

def start_uvicorn():
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run FastAPI server with uvicorn.")
    parser.add_argument('--host', type=str, default=SERVER, help='Server host [default: {SERVER}')
    parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, default=PORT, help='Server port [default: {PORT}]')
    parser.add_argument('--log-level', type=str, default='debug', help='Log level [default: debug]')
    parser.add_argument('--ssl-keyfile', type=str, default='key.pem', help='SSL key file path [default: key.pem]')
    parser.add_argument('--ssl-certfile', type=str, default='cert.pem', help='SSL certificate file path [default: cert.pem]')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    keyfile=fpath(args.ssl_keyfile)
    certfile=fpath(args.ssl_certfile)
    # Print debug info for SSL files
    if keyfile:
        print(f"Using SSL keyfile: {keyfile}")
        if not os.path.exists(keyfile):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"SSL keyfile not found: {keyfile}")
    else:
        print("No SSL keyfile provided")

    if certfile:
        print(f"Using SSL certfile: {certfile}")
        if not os.path.exists(certfile):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"SSL certfile not found: {certfile}")
    else:
        print("No SSL certfile provided")

    module_name = get_module_name()
  
    uvicorn.run(
        f"{module_name}:app",
        host=args.host,
        port=args.port,
        log_level=args.log_level,
        ssl_keyfile=keyfile,
        ssl_certfile=certfile
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_uvicorn()


I certainly don't want to start a holy war but Python is only going to be so fast, especially compared to an optimized C program.

Can you profile to determine which part of the code is taking most of the time?

@Nate Eldredge, good question.  We are working on getting timing at each step in the process.  I'll post new information when available.
